# Updating an Arcade-Style Scoreboard in Django with Posts from JQuery

Tags: jquery, django, http

I'm having a hard time determining how I should do this while avoiding potential issues on concurrency, etc.

A game in JQuery `POST`s a `Score` to an endpoint in Django. The goal is to store and display only the top 15 Scores and best simulate the behavior of a traditional arcade game.

The behavior should compare the new score to existing scores and only ask for the user's name if the new score would make it to the scoreboard, knocking off its lowest score.

So here are several thoughts I've had on how it could be done (and I'm not sure which Django functions and classes would be appropriate, either, so that help would be appreciated):

Method 1:

1. JQuery begins with a `POST`, `data={"score": [someNumber], "name": "False"}` to a lone url endpoint in Django, we'll say `url(r'^scoreboard$', scoreBoardView)`, so, `$.post("url.com/scoreboard", data, function(Response){ if Response == ...;})`.
2. The Django view branches based on the value of `name`, and assigns a variable `newScore` after getting the value of `score` from the post. (I'm not quite sure which Django methods pass and parse the POST into the view.)
3. The value of `newScore` is compared to existing scores and return a `True` or `False` response, depending on whether or not the score would make the rank. (I'm still thinking about the best way to do this one, too: My thought is that I sort the existing scores by value, compare to the new score to just the lowest value, and, if it's greater, I can just remove and replace the lowest score and only rank the scores on GET request).
4. If True, branch JQuery off into another `POST`, which has both a name and a score ( `data={"score": [someNumber], "name": "[someName]"}` , which removes the lowest ranked score and creates a new `Score` entry in the database.

Method 2:

1. Begin with a GET request for the all scores in the scoreboard (not sure what the URL params are for all).
2. Do the same comparison to existing scores, client-side.
3. Branch off if score is higher than lowest ranked score and POST.
4. Remove the lowest ranked score at the server.

Alternate:
Use either solution, but with separate endpoints. Do to the lack of large amounts of data, I shouldn't need to use the django-rest-framework.

Perhaps there are other options, as well. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I would advice to do at least the server-side version. The client side can be easily manipulated and invalid scores can be posted to your game.

If you request scores from the server to the client, you will have at least one advantage of not having to sent score requests to the server that are lower than the lowest on the list.

Because scores can be updated in realtime however, you will need a server side testing anyway, to see if a score is valid.

Answer (score 1):

I would do neither of these.

What I would recommend is that you return the top 15 results (whether or not it has your score) as a result of the post. So let's say there's fifteen scores 130, 120, 100, 97... 80 and then you post up a 76. It should return the same top fifteen scores no matter what. If you post a score that would replace one of the top fifteen, you should save it as a score to your database (I'd recommend keeping track of all scores unless you are seriously scrapped for disk space), and then return the top 15 which would then include your new score.

Hope this helps!

Comment: So, I've thought about this, and, this response is a little incomplete.
The database has 15 scores. Based on the type of arcade-style-leaderboard behavior I'm looking for, when the score is posted to the database and knocks off one of the top 15, the new score has to ask for initials. At this point, I need to have a default name entered in case the client chooses not to enter them. I'm still thinking a back-and-forth post-and-response to the server simulates the behavior, better, but concurrency becomes more of an issue with every request.